# Pentaho Report designer - parameterization on Locale Date format (~environment designtime- Locale)

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-report-designer

Irrespective of locale date format, I need to genereate the report with the date format of the locale which i passed in runtime. Am getting the expected results when I am editing fr in environment-designtime-locale and running it. But I want that to Dynamic.

Is anything doable in Penatho Report Desinger end to achieve it.

Finally I want the output in PDF fomrat with the dateformat am providing.

What I have already tried:

SQL level query modification is not accepted. Since for every date field we have to identify and do the query levle modification.

select FORMAT ( sample_date_field, 'f', ${Param_Locale} ) --> Param_Locale--> fr.

Comment: You  can pass via url (or) you can write  function in sql

Comment: Thanks for you reply . Can you please explain me breifly. Give some web link or code to explore it.

Comment: there is no proper documentation or link against your request.. the best way is write sql function and connect  you file with database and call the function..